# Why does $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{n+1}}$ diverge?

Tags: real-analysis, divergent-series

I guess it is kind of obvious that it diverges. But what divergent series do I compare it to?

Answer (score 4):

If you can use the fact that the harmonic series diverves, then, since$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\frac1{n+1}}{\frac1n}=1,$$your series diverges too.

Or you can use the fact that your series **is** the harmonic series minus its first term.

Another option here would be to use the integral test.

Comment: "Or you can use the fact that your series is the harmonic series minus its first term."

How?

Comment: A series $a_0+a_1+a_2+a_3+\cdots$ converges if and only if the series $a_1+a_2+a_3+a_4+\cdots$

Answer (score 3):

**This is because the convergence of a series does not depend on one term, it means that you can rest one term and it will still converge**

You have the divergent harmonic series without 1 term, lets see:

Suppose it converges to a real number $L$.

then $1+\displaystyle\sum_{n\ge1} \frac{1}{n+1}$ should converge to $L+1$

But $1+\displaystyle\sum_{n\ge1} \frac{1}{n+1}=\displaystyle\sum_{n\ge1} \dfrac{1}{n}$  and it should be equal to $L+1$, which is obviously false

Answer (score 2):

Compare to the harmonic series. Note that $$\frac{1}{n+1}=\frac 1n-\frac{1}{n(n+1)}.$$